# Define Color and Marker for each category specifically

Tags: python, seaborn

I am plotting some scatter plots, which are "temperature x element", and I want to set the legend to match two other parameters.

The thing is: I want to define the symbol and colour for each parameter so that all my legends have the same legends always.

For example:
Parameter 1 - Location
France: squares.
Portugal: circles.
Spain: triangles.

I have plot this:

```
sns.set_style("ticks")
sns.set_context("paper")
sns.relplot(data=bt, x="T", y="Li", hue="minerals", style="Location", palette="dark") 
plt.title("Li vs T")
plt.xlabel("T (°C)")
plt.ylabel("Li (ppm)")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ARsQ.png)

**However, the markers and colours are defined automatically, but I want to edit each category individually.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seaborn's `relplot` passes keyword arguments down to the axes-level plot, in this case `scatterplot` (the default `relplot`). The scatterplot [docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) explain that you can use the `markers` argument with a list or dictionary of markers, eg  `markers={'France': 's', 'Portugal': 'o', 'Spain': '^'}`. Valid markers in Matplotlib scatter charts are defined [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/markers_api.html#module-matplotlib.markers). So:

```
sns.relplot(data=bt, x="T", y="Li", hue="minerals", style="Location",
           palette="dark", markers={'France': 's', 'Portugal': 'o', 'Spain': '^'})
```